# Why companies spend a lot of money with Oracle?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql, oracle10g

Why not just postgresql or mysql ?
Is oracle very indispensable in some case ? In which case ?

Comment: PL/SQL is something what others can't provide. I think that is worth of spending your week money ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The above arguments are fluff.

Oracle provides stuff that the others don't, and does so where it matters.

- Oracle provides true read consistency without impacting its performance
- Oracle provides backup and recovery technologies that don't affect its performance
- Oracle provides a rich and mature featureset that the other platforms don't (i.e. FLASHBACK, RAC, Partitioning (in MySQL partitioning is still not implemented correctly), a rich programming environment, etc)

The most important:
Oracle provides instrumentation built into the kernal that let's you troubleshoot and diagnose performance issue very deeply.  No other platforms offer this.

There are lots more, but this is why it costs money.

Answer (score 9):

Let me clarify that I am no fan of Oracle in the first place and Oracle can definitely be a bit of a pain to start with (thats why they pay Oracle DBA's the earth) but there are a lot of pro's to Oracle.

1. Oracle has a rock solid reputation based on years and years of actual deployment in large (and i mean large) scale databases
2. Oracle used to be first and foremost a database company (not any more but it used to be) and most enterprises prefer knowing that they are going with a specialist rather than someone who "also" makes a database
3. Most enterprises prefer having the comfort of knowing that in case of issues they have tie-ups with the vendor who can be held accountable - which is not the case with open source stuff.
4. Oracle is a good database (sure, if u havent used it it takes some getting used to but that doesnt mean its not good. I have used SQL Server / Oracle / MySQL and though Oracle was a bit of a pain to start with, i do think its good).

Comment: I would also add that Oracle has more than "just" a database in der product line (talking of their application server and so on) and these work well together. Furthermore, you have paid support if you need it (Open Source support is good as well but being able to get help 24/7 by picking up the phone can be an important factor for big scale projects)

Comment: 1. Agreed, but other platforms are also "reliable".  2. On what basis do you make this claim.  The have more revenue than any other vendor.  They own MySQL and Sun and Java.  Seriously, no other vendor is as entrenched in the "enterprise".  3.  More fluff.  4.  More fluff.

Answer (score 7):

(paraphrasing) no one ever got fired for buying Oracle.